# Number theory based problem.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Problem statement,

> The greatest number which on dividing 1657 and 2037 leaves remainder 6 and 5 respectively.

Not sure how to begin with this problem. Is there any trick to these kind of problems?

Comment: Don't misuse the tags. This, just like your previous one, is `[elementary-number-theory]`

Comment: Find the common divisors of $1657-6$ and $2037-5$. Do you see why?

Comment: When you start a paragraph with long indentation, the software interprets it as a "verbatim" paragraph. It it displayed with no line breaks, no formatting, nothing. To get a paragraph that looks indented on display, precede the first character with `>` instead.

Comment: Please find better titles. Your frequent use of "word problem" and "based" as the full description is not good enough, and frankly, a problem.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Sorry about that. I will try to be more price in future.

Comment: look up the Chinese remainder theorem

Comment: @DavidLui CRT is the wrong tool here.

Answer (score 1):

Let $n$ be the greatest positive integer such that $1657 = 6 \text{ (mod n)}$ and $2037 = 5 \text{ (mod n)}$.

This implies that $n$ divides $1651$ and $2032$ evenly.

The prime factorizations of these numbers are $1651 = 13 \times 127$ and $2032 = 2^4 \times 127$.

$n$ must be the greatest common divisor of these numbers, so $\boxed{n = \gcd(1651, 2032) = 127}$.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs & PSQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).